# Reasons why Django was slow

Tags: python, database, django, performance

This is simply a question of curiosity. I have a script that loads a specific queryset without evaluating it, and then I print the `count()`. I understand that count has to go through so depending on the size it could potentially take some time, but it took **over a minute to return 0 as the count of an empty queryset** Why is that taking so long? is it Django or my server?

notes:

the queryset was all one type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on the query that you're running. If you're running a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo` on a table that has ten rows, it's going to be very fast; but if your query involves a dozen joins, sub-selects, filters on un-indexed rows--or if the target table simply has a lot of rows--the query can take an arbitrary amount of time.  In all likelihood, the bottleneck is not Django (although its ORM has some quirks), but rather the database and your query. Just because no rows meet the criteria doesn't mean that the database didn't need to deal with the other rows in the table.

Comment: That makes sense! But even though the QS is empty?

Comment: The query set is irrelevant. Think about going through a phone book; you might look for a phone number 901-555-1281, but never find it. However, if you're looking through a phone book for Cheyenne, Wyoming it's going to be a lot faster than looking through a phone book for New York... even though both 'query sets' are empty.

Comment: Okay, so my query is very complex, I will see if I can simplify it and get similar results. Thank you!

Comment: in case it helps to see the type of query after simplification, it is Model.filter(fkrelation__m2mrelation__in = list). It still seems to be  taking a while, but I assume this type of query is not that bad

Comment: That doesn't really say that much about it, sadly.  You'd probably have to look at the generated SQL and maybe run your database's query planner on it.  (If you're using Postgres, [`explain`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-explain.html) can be very helpful.)